# Each function is not working with setTimeout property using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `four boxes` that i want to come one by one from left side. But this is coming together. How can i solve this issue?

What i tried:-

```js
 $('.box').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
 setTimeout(function(){
   $this.addClass('unbox')
 },1000 );
 });
```

```css
.box{height:100px; width:100px; background:black; float:left; margin:10px; transform:translateX(-500px); transition:all 0.45s;}
.unbox{transform:translateX(0px); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer will be appreciated!

Comment: This issue is coming from the fact that setTimeout is asynchronous when each function is synchronous. Take a look at this article to understand both behaviours.
https://wsvincent.com/javascript-closure-settimeout-for-loop/

Comment: No guys, the error was simple. Didn't you notice that the numeric timeout is always the same?

Answer (score 3):

Give each box a progressively longer timeout. [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) passes an index as the first argument to its callback, which you can base the timeout delay on:

```js
 $('.box').each(function(i){
  var $this = $(this);
 setTimeout(function(){
   $this.addClass('unbox')
 },(i + 1) * 1000 );
 });
```

```css
.box{height:100px; width:100px; background:black; float:left; margin:10px; transform:translateX(-500px); transition:all 0.45s;}
.unbox{transform:translateX(0px); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script the foreach isn't wait for the timeout execution, you have 4 timeouts that starts with some milliseconds of difference. You can do in a lot of way to let the each loop become *sync*, but I think that there is a really simple solution to solve your problem **without overcomplicated** your script.

Just use an **index** and the on each cycle **add to your set timeout a bit of time**: setTimeout has not fixed 1000ms time but **1000*i** (index that change on every cycle).

```js
i=0;
$('.box').each(function(){
    i++;
  var $this = $(this);
 setTimeout(function(){
   $this.addClass('unbox')
 },i*1000 );
 });
```

```css
.box{height:100px; width:100px; background:black; float:left; margin:10px; transform:translateX(-500px); transition:all 0.45s;}
.unbox{transform:translateX(0px); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look into JS animation libraries such as GSAP (https://greensock.com/gsap/) for advance animation.

But for a quick fix, you can apply the following JS logic:-

```
$('.box').each(function(index){
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.addClass('unbox')
    }, index * 1000);
});
```

https://pastebin.com/eYmbmUjK